# React-Apollo Compose - Waiting for all chained graphql queries to finish

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a [High Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), in which I can pass an array of graphql query definitions to. This HOC also includes the [renderComponent from react-apollo recompose](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/recompose.html) to ensure that the component doesn't render if the graphql query is still running. The problem I am running into is that when I chain graphql queries, it renders the component before the second query has finished. So, I'm assuming that the first query finishes, and then the `props.data.loading` variable is set to `false`, so then the component renders. But, the second query never finishes. Here is my High Order Component:

```
const ErrorComponent = ({ error }) => (
    <span>
        Something went wrong: {JSON.stringify(error)}
    </span>
);

export function asContainer(Component, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, graphqlQueries = [], lifecycleSpec = {}) {
    const renderWhileLoading = () =>
        branch(
            props => props['data'] && props['data'].loading,
            renderComponent(Loader),
        );

    const renderForError = () =>
        branch(
            props => props['data'] && props['data'].error,
            renderComponent(ErrorComponent),
        );

    let parts = [connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)];

    if (graphqlQueries.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < graphqlQueries.length; i++) {
            let g = graphqlQueries[i];
            parts.push(graphql(g.query, g.opts))
        }
    }

    parts.push(
        lifecycle(lifecycleSpec),
        renderWhileLoading(),
        renderForError(),
        pure
    );

    return compose(parts)(Component);
}
```

And using the container pattern, this is the component that calls this HOC:

```
export const AuthedRouterContainer = asContainer(
    AuthedRouter,
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    [{
        name: "user",
        query: LoggedInUserQuery,
        opts: {
            options: (props) => ({
                variables: {
                    id: props.currentUser.id
                }
            }),
        }
    }, {
        query: GetEntityProcessesQuery,
        opts: {
            name: "processes",
            options: (props) => ({
                variables: {
                    entityId: props.currentEntity.id
                }
            }),
            skip: (props) => !props.currentEntity
        }
    }]
);
```

I need help figuring out why this doesn't wait for the second query to finish before rendering the component being passed into the HOC.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `renderWhileLoading(LoadingComponent)` ? (same for `renderForError`). Might be unrelated but did you try without the `pure` enhancer ?

Comment: I have that being imported above since I will use the same LoadingComponent everywhere. But, removing the `pure` enhancer did it.

Comment: Glad it helped :)